# Instagram Home Feed

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, feed

I'm creating an app using Android Studio which integrates social networks.
I'm attempting to retrieve my instagram home feed.

I've found the following URL "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" however this is not in the instagram developers documentation and when I replace `ACCESS_TOKEN` with my access token, I am told that the page isn't available.

Is there no way anymore to get the home feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram has made some [pretty significant changes](http://developers.instagram.com) to their API this month.

If your app conforms to their current requirement, you should be able to query different endpoints depending on your requirement. Most of the tutorials/solutions found on the web will likely be outdated.

Your best bet is to refer to the [documentation pertaining to endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

Comment: Just to clarify. Its not possible anymore to load the images from the account I am following through a simple endpoint (self/feed)?

The endpoint self/media/recent is only loading the images that I uploaded.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you're trying to obtain the images from an account you're _following_? If that is the case, the endpoint that would work is 'api.instagram.com/v1/users{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-‌​TOKEN' 
Your app would also need to contain public_content scope. If your desired use case isn't currently documented, it is unlikely it will pass their review, at least in the short term. It's also a moot point if your app mimics the functionality of Instagram in any way.